# Uri().AbsolutePath "Unexpected symbol '.' in binding." error expression in F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have such a statement in C#:

```cs
    private static string LogPath
    {
        get
        {
            string filePath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath;
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath) + "/cube_solver_log.txt";
        }
    }
```

When I try to write it in F#;

```
static member LogPath() =
    let filePath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath
    Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath) + "/cube_solver_log.txt"
```

I encounter an exception:

> Unexpected symbol '.' in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.

Because in F#, I don't know why, System library doesn't accept .`AbsolutePath` in my code.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Have you opened the `System.Reflection` namespace?

Comment: No, I haven't. Let me try. :)

Comment: Ahh sorry sorry I've already opened System.Reflection. :)

Comment: Also use `Path.CombinePath()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add brackets around the `new` expression:

```ml
static member LogPath() =
    let filePath = (new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath
    Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath) + "/cube_solver_log.txt"
```

in fact the `new` keyword is optional so you can do:

```ml
let  LogPath() =
    let filePath = Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath
    Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath) + "/cube_solver_log.txt"
```